# Create multiple clocks in a generated list with button click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like the user to choose a desired timezone from a dropdown, click Add and display the time. Easy enough. But I would also like the user to be able to add additional clocks for other timezones.
I have run into 2 problems that contradict each other:

1. I can add clocks to the list, but they don't advance with setInterval because I need to make the id's unique for the list, which creates an error.
2. If I eliminate the unique id variable (unique++), then the clocks work, but each time a new clock it created, they just overwrite each other because their id's are NOT unique.

Code and jsfiddle below:

```js
var t; 
var nd;
var uniqueID = 0;

// add timezone clock and add 1 to uniqueID counter
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('addTimeZone').addEventListener('click', getSelectTime);
    document.getElementById('addTimeZone').addEventListener('click', addUniqueID);
});

//add 1 to uniqueID everytime the 'Add' button is clicked
function addUniqueID() {
    uniqueID++;
}
function getSelectTime() {
    //create space for new list item
    document.getElementById("addedClock").style.display = "block";
    
    //get timezone offset from dropdown
    var t = document.getElementById("timezone").value;
    
    //build new list item
    var list = document.getElementById('newClocks');
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    list.appendChild(entry);
    
    //add div to list to display time and add unique id
    var divValue = document.createElement("div");
    divValue.id = 'resultTZValue' + uniqueID;
    entry.appendChild(divValue);
    
    //run clock function, pass the timezone offset and uniqueID
    tzClock(t , uniqueID);
    setInterval(() => {tzClock(t , uniqueID); }, 1000);
}
function tzClock(t , uniqueID) { 
    var d = new Date();
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000 * t)).toLocaleTimeString();
    
    //plug this new time data into list item
    document.getElementById("resultTZValue" + uniqueID).innerHTML = nd ;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Good Times</title>    
<style>
li {list-style-type: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="addedClock" class="infoContainer" style="display:none">
    <ol id="newClocks"></ol>
</div>
<div class="addTimeZone">
    <div class="dropDown"> 
        <form>
          <label for="timezone">Add Additional Timezone:</label>
          <select name="timezone" id="timezone">
            <option value="">Choose</option>
            <option value="0" >Universal Coordinated Time</option>
            <option value="-5">Eastern Standard</option>
            <option value="-6">Central Standard</option>
            <option value="-7">Mountain Standard</option>
            <option value="-8">Pacific Standard</option>
          </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="addBtn"> 
        <button id='addTimeZone'>Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/scottschaffer/7sx9b1oe/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two ways you can fix that.

**First option**

Calling the function inside another in the `setInterval` function will cause it to always get the global variable, so instead of `setInterval(() => {tzClock(t , uniqueID); }, 1000)`  call it like `setInterval(tzClock, 1000, t, uniqueID)`. [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gunterberg/wyg7389e/2/).

**Second option**

You can always pass the element as parameter instead of the id, so you can just use `divValue` you created and call `element.innerHTML` instead of `document.getElementById(...).innerHTML`. [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gunterberg/uL56xbw2/3/).

Comment: Thanks @Gunther! But the clocks are not running in your examples. They just post the static time. My problem is that the clocks don't run.

Comment: @scott.schaffer sorry, apparently jsFiddle didn't save my changes, I've updated the links, try again please.

Comment: dude!!!  thank you so much! Ive been banging my head with this one. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Heres my solution:

Move `uniqueID++` inside `getSelectTime` function at start.

Then create array inside it and start set interval for each clock.

```
  let arr = [];
  arr.push(uniqueID)
  arr.forEach(clock => {
    setInterval(() => {
      tzClock(t, clock);
    }, 1000);
  })
```

```js
var t;
var nd;
var uniqueID = 0;

// add timezone clock and add 1 to uniqueID counter
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('addTimeZone').addEventListener('click', getSelectTime);
});


function getSelectTime() {
  uniqueID++
  //create space for new list item
  document.getElementById("addedClock").style.display = "block";

  //get timezone offset from dropdown
  var t = document.getElementById("timezone").value;

  //build new list item
  var list = document.getElementById('newClocks');
  var entry = document.createElement('li');
  list.appendChild(entry);

  //add div to list to display time and add unique id
  var divValue = document.createElement("div");
  divValue.id = 'resultTZValue' + uniqueID;
  entry.appendChild(divValue);

  //run clock function, pass the timezone offset and uniqueID
  tzClock(t, uniqueID);
  
  let arr = [];
  arr.push(uniqueID)
  arr.forEach(clock => {
    setInterval(() => {
      tzClock(t, clock);
    }, 1000);
  })
}


function tzClock(t, uniqueID) {
  var d = new Date();
  utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
  nd = new Date(utc + (3600000 * t)).toLocaleTimeString();

  //plug this new time data into list item
  document.getElementById("resultTZValue" + uniqueID).innerText = nd;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Good Times</title>
  <style>
    li {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="addedClock" class="infoContainer" style="display:none">
    <ol id="newClocks"></ol>
  </div>
  <div class="addTimeZone">
    <div class="dropDown">
      <form>
        <label for="timezone">Add Additional Timezone:</label>
        <select name="timezone" id="timezone">
          <option value="">Choose</option>
          <option value="0">Universal Coordinated Time</option>
          <option value="-5">Eastern Standard</option>
          <option value="-6">Central Standard</option>
          <option value="-7">Mountain Standard</option>
          <option value="-8">Pacific Standard</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="addBtn">
      <button id='addTimeZone'>Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is also a great answer